# How to unzip multiple files in a different directory

Tags: python, file, unzip

I have 4 folders in `my_directory` (A, B, C, and D). Each folder contains 1 or more zipped file(s). Each zipped file contains 1  `txt` file. I also have another directory named `my_counterpart`, this directory is empty.

Now I want 2 things:

1. I want to unzip all the files from the 5 folders in my_directory the same folders but then in 'my_counterpart'.
2. I also want to change the name of the files as soon as they get unzipped, I want to add `date_of_file` to the file name. (I don't know how to do this).

**This is my code:**

```
my_directory = r'c:\data\DAS\Desktop\my_directory'
my_counterpart = r'c:\data\DAS\Desktop\my_counterpart' 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            date_of_file = re.search('-(.\d+)-', file).group(1) #<- extract the date of the zipped files. 
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file) #<- the file paths of the files in my_directory
                           
            zip_object = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path) #<- the zipped objects of the files in my_directory
                                        
            new_file_path = os.path.join(my_counterpart, dirs) #<- make the file paths for my_counterpart          
            os.makedirs(new_file_path)  #<- create the directories of my_directory in my_counterpart
                        
            zip_object.extractall(new_file_path) #<- extract all the files in my_counterpart
            zip_object.close()
```

I don't know if the way I wrote is correct because it doesn't do what I intended it to do and it also gives me back the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\My_files\Official_part1.py", line 55, in <module>
    new_file_path = os.path.join(middle_stage, dirs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 153, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

Comment: `dirs` is a list, not a string

Comment: Please [edit] to show the full traceback.

Comment: @tripleee See edited code, traceback now Included.@mousetail, I know its a list, but how do I fix it?

Comment: The traceback is triggered by a line of code that is different from what you put in your question.`dirs` is the list of subdirectories of the current directory in the walk, i.e. don’t understand why you’re using it. You probably want to adapt from `root`. Add some print statements to show yourself what the values of root, dirs and files are.

Comment: @barny I want that subdirectories to be in my `my_counterpart`. After that I want to unzipp all the files inside that subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, but I thought the files are in the subdirectories? By the time your walk is at the folder with your files, dirs is the (possibly empty) list of subdirectories of that folder, i.e. it’s not the path to that folder, that’s in root. print the values of root dirs and files, you’ll see what I mean.

Comment: As you have a fixed folder structure, you might find it easier using `glob()` like `zipfiles=glob.glob(*/*.zip”)`

Comment: @barny where would I need to put that? Can you show me the whole sript please so I understand  the process?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t offer a code-writing service. Just try it, is my advice.